# SQL Server 2008 R2: Dynamic Pivot table query performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the following table with the records:

**Example**:

**Table Name**: Test

```
 cola   colb  colc
-------------------
 111    222   A1
 111    333   A2
 111    344   A3
 111    444   A4
 5443   555   B1
 767    222   A1
 767    333   A2
 767    344   A3
 8998   222   A1
 8998   333   A2
```

**What I want to do with this data**: I want to show the pivot table with some specific `colc` values which are belongs to `cola` values only not others. For example in the below script shown that `A1,A2,A3` belongs to  `767` exactly not more or less then that.

**Note**: The below script works fine with the expected result **BUT** the problem is with the query performance because I am joining many times the same table which is of millions of records which cause me waiting for long while loop.

**Pivot table script**:

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)
Declare @stuff varchar(max) = 'A1,A2,A3'

SET @sql = 'SELECT cola,Available,'+@Stff+'
           FROM                     
           (
                SELECT  v.cola,v.colc,c.Available
                FROM tft AS v   
                inner join
                (
                   select cola,count(distinct colc) AS Available
                   FROM tft a
                   where colc in ('+@stuff+')
                   group by cola
                   having(select count(DISTINCT colc) 
                   from tft b where b.cola= a.cola and colc in('+@stuff+'))= 3
                   and (select count(DISTINCT colc) from tft c where c.cola = a.cola) = 3
                ) c 
                on c.cola = v.cola
           ) p                     
           PIVOT                
           (            
                count(colc)                        
                FOR colc IN ('+@stuff+')                        
           ) AS pvt';   

print(@sql);
exec(@sql);
```

**Problem**: The problem is with the huge records which makes a delay for long while. Is there any better way to write same concept?

Comment: Start killing the distincts. These likely cost you time. Then go on and post a query plan.

Comment: @TomTom, If I does that then I am unable to get result. :(

Comment: @TomTom, Because I want to count distinct `colc` in the having clause.

Comment: THen you are stuck - Especially as you ginore requests for query plans.Distinct is quite evil. Get rid of it. Heck, a GROUP BY could easily replace it. Query plan please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate way, it avoids the `DISTINCT`s and uses a sum instead of the pivot function:

```
SELECT  orig.cola ,
        colas.counter ,
        SUM(CASE orig.colc WHEN 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1 ,
        SUM(CASE orig.colc WHEN 'A2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A2 ,
        SUM(CASE orig.colc WHEN 'A3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A3
FROM    tft orig
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT cola ,
                            COUNT(1) AS counter
                     FROM   ( SELECT    cola ,
                                        colc
                              FROM      tft 
                              WHERE     cola NOT IN (
                                        SELECT  cola
                                        FROM    tft 
                                        WHERE   colc NOT IN ( 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' ) )
                              GROUP BY  cola ,
                                        colc
                            ) a
                     GROUP BY cola
                     HAVING COUNT(1) > 2
                   ) colas ON colas.cola = orig.cola
GROUP BY orig.cola ,
        colas.counter
```

I have tested it and it returns the same results as your query using your sample data.